# Samba share not working

Tags: archlinux

I want to configure a Samba share with guest read and write access. 
Here is my *smb.conf* file :

```
[global]
workgroup = WORKGROUP
server string = Rpi Samba Server
security = user

[nas]
path = /media/nas
browseable = yes
read only = no
guest ok = yes
force user = pi
locking = no
writable = yes
```

The shared folder has the following permissions :

```
drwxr-xr-x 4 pi users 4096 Apr 11 21:16 nas
```

There is nothing complicated with this config. The Samba daemon is using the *pi* user (who has correct UNIX file permissions) to write to the directory. It used to work fine using the Raspbian distro. However, when I want to create a folder or a file inside the share using my file manager (Thunar), it seems I don't have write access. The *smbd.log* outputs this :

```
[2013/04/11 21:28:27.391104,  0] smbd/trans2.c:1253(unix_filetype)
unix_filetype: unknown filetype 0
```

Anyone help ?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/31298/samba-users-cant-write-to-dirs-not-created-by-themselves is this related?

Comment: @mishka this doesn't belong here, try [questions related to samba](http://serverfault.com/search?q=samba) on serverfault.com

Comment: @LadislavDANKO This question is actually perfectly fine. Any question related to the Raspberry Pi is on topic in accordance with the [faq]. Mainly because we don't like to migrate questions needlessly.

Answer (score 1):

Global directive 
[guest account](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html#GUESTACCOUNT) resolved the issue.
It tells Samba which UNIX user to use to access the file system.

So my config is like this :

```
[global]
workgroup = WORKGROUP
server string = Rpi Samba Server
security = user
guest account = pi

[nas]
comment = Serveur NAS
path = /media/nas
browseable = yes
read only = no
guest ok = yes
writable = yes
```

Unfortunatly this parameter is not available per share.

Glad if it helps